# XML validation using XSD (regex) with "|" operator (Notepad++ plugin)

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, notepad++, xsd-validation

I am using following not very strict XSD validation (regular expression) to check if a string contains `https` or relative URLs and not `http`.

```
<xs:attribute name="src">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:pattern value="(.{4}[^:].*)|(.{1,4})"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Sample XML:

```
Succeeds (suppose to fail)    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html src="http://www.stackoverflow.com" /> 
Succeeds (as expected)        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html src="https://www.stackoverflow.com" />
Succeeds (as expected)        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html src="relative/url.html" />
```

This is working as intended when I verified with an online validator:

- [https](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=5efb46d4-f17c-4abd-8e4a-da32ed272f65-xsdvalidation)
- [http](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=e31a20f6-c909-4594-9286-75bde358e439-xsdvalidation)

When I verified against Notepad++ XML plugin to validate, this is failing. The expression works individually though `"(.{4}[^:].*)`" and `"(.{1,4})"` but not together with `"|"` operator (or).

Does the XSD validation work differently on Notepad++ with OR operator? Is there a fix or am I missing something here?

This looks to be an issue with XMLLint (Linux) also as one of my colleagues verified it.

Comment: I think you need to group the `or`, e.g.  `(?:(.{4}[^:].*)|(.{1,4}))`.

Comment: @chris85, thanks for the comment. It doesn't function; throws "unable to parse schema file..."

Comment: If `(.{4}[^:].*|.{1,4})` does not solve the issue, try to just double the attribute: `<xs:pattern value=".{4}[^:].*"/><xs:pattern value=".{1,4}"/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no point in just using `.` since we are checking for exact character sequences. To require all the links to start with `https` and not `http`, you can use:

```
<xs:pattern value="https.*"/>
```

Or even

```
<xs:pattern value="https://.*"/>
```

**EDIT**:

For relative URLs like `relative/url.html`, you can add `(?:[^/]*/)*[^/]+\.[^.]+` subpattern:

```
<xs:pattern value="https://.*|(?:[^/]*/)*[^/]+\.[^.]+"/>
```

Comment: I think that's a misreading of the XSD rules. `<xs:pattern value="http|https"/>` means `^http$|^https$`, not `^http|https$`

Comment: @MichaelKay: Highly possible, but anyway, the regex for checking https URLs definitely needs revision.

Comment: @stribizhev, in my initial post I forgot to mention about relative URLs. Regex need to validate "https" or "relative URLs" excluding any "http"

Comment: What are relative URLs then? Those starting with `/`? Then you can try `"https.*|/.*"`.

Comment: Please check, I have updated the answer. Also, I set up [a demo to see what should be captured with the regex](https://regex101.com/r/tW8vN3/1).

Comment: Happy to help. If my answer proved helpful, please also consider upvoting.